Find uniques in two sheets and populate rows
I need to compare the first two columns of sheet A into the first two columns of sheet B to find uniques, populate the other values in each row and then put the results in alphabetical order.
Like this:

The formula found in this solution works well to filter the uniques:
=filter(A1:A, isna(match(A1:A, 'SheetB'!A1:A,0)))

the only problem is that it doesn't automatically populate the other values in the corresponding row.
What formula do I need to make this work?


You may try:
=sort(filter(A:C,isna(xmatch(A:A&B:B,SheetB!A:A&SheetB!B:B))))


Just for confirmation, the C column in your formula is necessary because the  formula needs a place to elaborate the request, correct?

Column C is added because your desired output shows the email as well to be included
